# What's the event fired when user selects some text on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, events

Either by double click or move the mouse.

Anyone knows about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can bind a function to `document.onmouseup` to call `document.getSelection()`? This is assuming your users use mouse to select the text ;)

```
document.onmouseup = function() {
  var sel = document.getSelection();
  if (sel.length > 0) {
    alert(sel);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you refer to the `select`event. See here: http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javaevents.html

Comment: I mean the entire page,not just textarea or input.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be `document.getSelection()`?

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/HTML/CapturingaTextSelection.htm)'s a web page on that subject.

Comment: I mean the event,not the content.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use "onselect", but it works just for form elements (inputs, selects...).

```
function on_select() {
    alert( "selected" );
}
```

...

```
<input name="input" onselect="on_select()">
```

Answer (score 0):

In IE only the `select` event applies to body text as well as form inputs, so would do what you want. IE and WebKit have `selectstart` which fires when the users starts selecting, which probably won't help you. To detect when the user has made a selection in a cross-browser way you will need to handle both `keyup` and `mouseup` events. Even then you won't be detecting selection events such as the user using the "Select all" menu option (usually found in the Edit and right click context menus). The situation is not ideal in current browsers.