# How to select event in div?

Tags: html, contenteditable

```
<div id="container" style="border: 1px solid #333" contentEditable="true">Type text    here</div>
```

Is there a function to be triggered when I select text? (`Type text here`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get a Javascript event from the selection of text outside of text or textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791526/can-i-get-a-javascript-event-from-the-selection-of-text-outside-of-text-or-texta)

Comment: check my solution... your problem is solved....

Comment: @FahimParkar: Not really. Selection can also be triggered by the keyboard or by the edit and context menus.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind a handler to a selection change on window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991511/how-to-bind-a-handler-to-a-selection-change-on-window)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you want by using `onMouseUp` event. See below...

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="border: 1px solid #333" contentEditable="true" onMouseUp="checkMe()">Type text    here</div>

    </body>
    <script language="javascript">
    function checkMe() {
        var txt = "";

        if (window.getSelection) {
            txt = window.getSelection();
        } else if (document.getSelection) {
            txt = document.getSelection();
        } else if (document.selection) {
            txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }

        alert("Selected text is " + txt);
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: There's also keyboard selections and "Select all" from the edit and context menus to consider.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onMouseUp event and check if there is a selection as in this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2gLLp/

see also:
http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have used selection changed event you can try that

```
    document.addEventListener('selectionchange', (e)=>{
        console.log("Archor node - ",window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement);
    });
```